# Toggle divs for open/close with Derek Perez PageSlide

Tags: jquery, toggle, html

I'm trying to use [Derek Perez PageSlide Plugin for jQuery](http://derekperez.com/jquery-pageslide/demo/) in a Wordpress site. Default beahaviour is a link to open it, and click anywhere else on the page to close it.

I would like to toggle images saying "open" when it's closed and "close" when it's open.
So I have played around with jquery toggle() and enclosing the links in divs but can't get it to work. I can get 2 simple divs to toggle, but not with link content.

**open link:**
`<a href="_right.html" id="slide-right">`

**close link:**
`<a  href="javascript:;" class="pageslide-close">`

**Below enclosed in divs with images to clarify:**
`<div id="opendiv">`
`<a href="_right.html" id="slide-right"><img src="open.png"></a>`
`</div>`

`<div id="closediv">`
`<a  href="javascript:;" class="pageslide-close"><img src="close.png"></a>`
`</div>`

Any ideas? Thank's /Bo

**Edit:**
Seems like the below script part, that has to be located at the very bottom of the page, interrupts the execution of the jquery toggle() function. Ideas?

`<script type="text/javascript">`
    `$("#slide-left").pageSlide({ width: "350px", direction: "left" });`
    `$("#slide-right").pageSlide({ width: "350px", direction: "right" });`
    `$("#slide-modal").pageSlide({ width: "350px", direction: "left", modal: true });`
  `</script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I put the toggle() function in head instead of in page and problem was solved!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function() {
   $("div.mis").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```